# MySQLi cannot create new table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I'm getting frustrated with running basic SQL statements in PHP. I keep running into syntax errors that ask me to refer to the current server version of MySQL.

I'm trying to run the follow SQL query:

```
CREATE DATABASE mc_todo_app;

use mc_todo_app;

CREATE TABLE todos (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    task VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    completed BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

In PHP I then try to run this script.

```
require "config.php";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = file_get_contents('data/init.sql');
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (false === $result) {
  printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
} else {
  echo "DB and Table successfully created!";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

This produces the following error message:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'use mc_todo_app;
>       CREATE TABLE todos (
>           id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
>           tas' at line 3

Here are the details of my Database server:
[image]

I'm even trying basic Table creation statements from W3Schools without success.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `mysqli_query` exeutes one query.

Comment: @u_mulder Still cannot run the create table query.

Comment: You expect me to guess the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli_query()` can only execute one query at a time, while you are attempting to execute multiple queries. You can use `mysqli_multi_query()` instead.

```
$sql = file_get_contents('data/init.sql');
$result = mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql);
```

- http://php.net/mysqli.multi-query